# Wordpress: use custom category template (category.php) for different custom post type

Tags: wordpress, templates

i need to customize my `category.php` template depending of which custom post type the cat is attached (assuming every post type has dedicated categories, not shared between pt, and dynamically created by site admin user).

Alternative to this can be load different template (category-slug.php?) but codex says `category.php` is only and one.

Any suggestion?

Solved by a link provided by Vasanthan.R.P
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/custom-post-types-on-category-pages

Comment: what you are asking here is quite broad and not specific. have you tried going to the category.php to customize. and if you have any problem, come back and ask.

Comment: Did you try category-slug.php? You can use slug or id to create different template for each category. See here for more reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: @ Vasanthan non posso farlo, perché la lumaca (categorie alias) vengono creati dal proprietario del sito web e non sono fisse. Ho bisogno di someting come categoria posttypeslug.php

@bingjie2680 i try to be more specific: i have some cats attached to 2 CPT, i need to show in different ways the pages "category x" depending of one or other CPT. the problem is that the template category.php is only one. 
The category.php is a grid of products, each linked to the single detail page (done).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this solution.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/category-template-for-custom-post-type

or you can try this one too

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/custom-post-types-on-category-pages

Comment: the second link solve my problem!
thank you!
i report solution in the OP for future readers!